# Using ListInterpolation to get a vector-valued function

Tags: interpolation

I wanted to construct a `ColorFunction` from an image, so I tried

```
im = Image@
  ReliefPlot[
   Table[Sin[Abs@x - Abs@y], {x, -π, π, π/100}, {y, -π, π, π/100}],
   PlotRangePadding -> None]

cf = ListInterpolation[ImageData[im], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because ImageData is an `n * m * 3` list. However, I *don't* want to interpolate the third dimension, the resulting interpolating function should return a *vector*. I expected to find a relevant example in the *Possible issues* section, but alas, there is none.

The following approaches work:

```
cf = ListInterpolation[
  Apply[RGBColor, ImageData@im, {2}], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

But then there's really no interpolation (interpolation order zero). A better approach:

```
cf = With[{f = 
    ListInterpolation[ImageData@im, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 3}}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> {3, 3, 1}]}, 
       (RGBColor @@ {f[##, 1], f[##, 2], f[##, 3]}) &]
```

But I'm not sure if that's the best way.

So the general question is **"how can one do a `ListInterpolation` of a list of vectors?"** and a follow-up to it is **"how can I make my approach cleaner and minimize any unnecessary overhead?"**

For the general case (i.e. not building a `ColorFunction`, but simply interpolating an array of vectors) I prefer to not have to know anything about the structure of my list beforehand, except that it is a non-ragged `n+1` dimensional array and I want a function of `n` arguments that returns a vector.

Addendum:

To make it absolutely clear, a vector-valued `InterpolationFunction` is quite possible, and indeed, the following is probably the ideal result for me:

```
With[{dim = (Most@Dimensions@ImageData@im - 1)},
 Interpolation[
   Flatten[MapIndexed[{(#2 - 1)/dim, #1} &, ImageData@im, {2}],
     Length[dim] - 1]]]
```

What I don't like here, is that I'm forced to restructure the whole list and get the correct dimensions and all that, when `ListInterpolation` can do almost everything for me (except for vector values).

Comment: Can you note in your question that `Interpolation` does support interpolating arbitrary dimensional vectors?  Just to get this out of the way.

Comment: You *could* use `Interpolation` instead of `ListInterpolation`, but settling for three `ListInterpolations` might be easier actually.  Personally I would go for three `ListInterpolations`.

Comment: @Szabolcs done and included a possible solution. However I want MMA to do my work for me :)

Comment: Do you know that there is [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) specifically intended for interpolation between colors?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I struggle to gather from the documentation, that blend supports two-dimensional interpolation. Possibly, nested `Blend`s could work, but I expect this to be rather slow.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov what I meant is a 2d array of colors, between which I want to interpolate: `colorarr = {{Red, Green, Blue}, {Yellow, Cyan, Magenta},{Gray, Black,White}};f = Function[{x, y}, Blend[Blend[#, x] & /@ colorarr, y]];RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> f]`

Comment: Can this be done without nesting the `Blend`s? I'm not so sure.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov `data = colorarr = Map[RGBColor, ImageData[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], {2}];` then define `f` as nested `Blend`s as above. The interpolation is forced to re-evaluate at every call to `f` and is extremely slow. Interpolate the entire table of channel values first, as I show in my answer, and the `RegionPlot` is rendered almost instantly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is sad that `Blend` is completely re-evaluated at each call. They certainly could do this better.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov The problem is slightly different. `Blend` re-evaluates, because the `Function` has attributes `HoldAll`. The problem is, that `Blend` does not support a symboli second argument, that would allow to code that nested construct in a faster manner. I think, it would not be too hard to roll a `myBlend` that does support symbolic arguments. In fact, most of the work is already done in this QA.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a pretty clean way of doing this. `Interpolation` and `ListInterpolation` support interpolation of symbolic values. I use this to hide the fact that the data is an `n+1` dimensional array.

```
Module[{a},
 Evaluate[Array[a, Most@Dimensions@data]] = data;
 Block[{a}, ListInterpolation[Array[a, Most@Dimensions@data]]]]
```

Explanation:

- To avoid unnecessary garbage I localize `a` with `Module`.
- Then I place my data into the `DownValues` of `a`.
- At this point `ListInterpolation[Array[a, Most@Dimensions@data]]` would see an `n+1`-dimensional list with scalar output. However...
- ... if I `Block` `a`, then this is simply an `n`-dimensional list with symbolic output.
- Inside the block an `InterpolationFunction` is created, which is a normal Mathematica expression, with `a[i,j]` explicitly in the arguments.
- As soon as the `Block` is exited, the `a[i,j]` are replaced with the vector values and that rolls fine with `InterpolationFunction`.

**EDIT**

The code above works if the data range is not specified. Today I noticed, that if the data range *is* specified, the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `ListInterpolation` inside the `Block` contains `a[1., 1.]...` (that is, real indices) instead of `a[1, 1]...` (integer indices).

This undesirable behavior is in itself worth another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107994/26956).

Over there AlexeyPopkov suggests a clean workaround, by giving `a` the attribute `NHoldAll`:

```
Module[{a},
 Evaluate[Array[a, Most@Dimensions@data]] = data;
 a[idx__Real] := a @@ (Floor /@ {idx});
 Block[{a}, SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll]; 
   ListInterpolation[Array[a, Most@Dimensions@data], datarange]]]
```

**EDIT 06.05.16**

JasonB observes quite bad performance for this approach, and I'm, so far, not sure of the exact cause. But a workaround was quick enough to find: simply construct the appropriate arguments for `InterpolatingFunction` directly.

```
quickIntFunc[data_] :=
 InterpolatingFunction[
  {{1, 1}, Most@Dimensions@data} // Transpose,
  {5, 3, 0, Most@Dimensions@data, {4, 4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
  Range /@ (Most@Dimensions@data),
  Map[List] /@ data,
  {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

Comment: For some reason this method is very slow sometimes, slower than building a list of interpolation functions.  I tried to use this to simplify a code where the array dimensions are the rows and columns of an image and the vector is the RGB colors.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/3DJbRctk) is the example code, it takes a long time to build up the interpolating function using your method.

Comment: @JasonB yes, interpolation of symbolic stuff takes a while, I'm seeing that. Subsequent replacement of `a[x,y]` with actual rgb values also takes a long time. And the interpolation of a list of `{{{x1,y1},{r1,g1,b1}}...}` is also atrociously long. I'll see if things could be sped up, as I don't see, why a vector-valued function absolutely must be 20 times slower to construct.

Comment: @JasonB see latest edit, this should suit your needs and performs 10x faster on my machine, (though a bit slower, than constructing 3 one-dimensional-output interpolations).

Comment: I will check it out, although I think I found a pretty decent solution to the problem, going to fill in the details on a new answer

Answer (score 2):

This will build an interpolating function off of a n-dimensional array, that, when given `n-1` arguments, returns a list whose length is the last value of `Dimensions[array]`.

```
arrayInterpolation[array_] :=
  Through@*(ListInterpolation[#] & /@ 
     Transpose[array, RotateLeft@Range@(Depth@array - 1)]);
```

We can test it out,

```
testarray = RandomReal[1, {4, 4, 4, 4, 7}];
testfunc = arrayInterpolation[testarray];

testarray[[1, 2, 1, 2]]
testfunc[1, 2, 1, 2]
(* {0.862862, 0.566754, 0.311709, 0.734644, 0.982298, \
0.516959, 0.200609} *)
(* {0.862862, 0.566754, 0.311709, 0.734644, 0.982298, \
0.516959, 0.200609} *)
```

So it reproduces the data exactly, and it also interpolates:

```
ListPlot[{testarray[[1, 2, 1, 2]], testarray[[1, 2, 1, 3]], 
  testfunc[1, 2, 1, 2.5]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"vector 1", "vector 2", "interpolation"}]
```

[image]

Comment: If someone knows a better way to make a single function that returns a list of values, when you have a list of functions, like a reverse of `Map` that'd be great.  `(Function[func, func[##]] /@ listoffunctions &)` just feels hacky.

Comment: I think, that's `Through`

Comment: `Through@*cf1` instead of what you had in the last line of the module works just fine. Also fixed a typo - you had `testarray` in the module but localized `array`.

Comment: Thanks, also thanks for catching the typo

Comment: no problem. Personally I prefer to use the composed form `Through@*cf1`, rather than nesting `Function[Through[cf1[##]]]`, because `Function` has attributes `HoldAll` and every call to it will introduce extra evaluation, but I think, in this case there's no difference. +1 in any case.

Comment: Ja, I just don't fully understand compositions that well so this is where I landed.

Comment: I'm abusing the comment section, but apparently there is a more important reason to use `Composition` or at least put an `Evaluate` in the body of your `Function`. If your `Module` is run as is, `f = arrayInterpolation[data]` returns `Through[cf1$369[##1]]&`. After clearing `Clear[cf1$369]`, `f` no longer works.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP - ugh, it bothers me to no end that you can have access to local `Module` variables outside of the `Module`.  It feels like a moral injustice to me   :-)