# Why does `ListInterpolation` convert integers to reals in the internal representation?

Tags: interpolation

This problem is mentioned in my self-answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106079/26956).

Here is an illustration of the problem:

```
f1 = ListInterpolation[Array[a, 10]];
f2 = ListInterpolation[Array[a, 10], {{1, 10}}];
f3 = ListInterpolation[Array[a, 10], {{1., 10.}}];
f1 === f2
f2 === f3
(* True *)
(* False *)

InputForm[f1]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 10}}, {5, 3, 0, {10},
> {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, 
> {{a[1]}, {a[2]}, {a[3]}, {a[4]}, {a[5]}, {a[6]}, {a[7]}, {a[8]}, {a[9]}, {a[10]}},
> {Automatic}]
> ```

```
InputForm[f3]
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 10.}}, {5, 3, 0, {10},
> {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
> {{1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.}},
> {{a[1.]}, {a[2.]}, {a[3.]}, {a[4.]}, {a[5.]}, {a[6.]}, {a[7.]}, {a[8.]}, {a[9.]}, {a[10.]}},
> {Automatic}]
> ```

Note how the values are stored in each `InterpolatingFunction` - a list of `a[i]`. Except, as soon as we introduced a real domain (`{1., 10.}`) instead of integer (`{1, 10}`), `ListInterpolation` converted the integer indices of `a` to real values.

Now I cannot do this:

```
Evaluate[Array[a, 10]] = RandomReal[10, {10}];
Plot[f3[x],{x,1,10}] (* returns empty plot *)
```

However this works:

```
Plot[{f1[x],f2[x]},{x,1,10}]
(* returns a random curve through 10 points, as it should *)
```

I know, how to fix this, a solution is mentioned in my answer.

**Question:** is this a bug? Or are there reasons for this behavior? Do note, that not **all** integers are converted to reals, but I see no reason for the indices to be affected. Could it be applying `N` to the list of values?

Comment: It seems you are right: `N` is applied internally in the case of `f3`. You can protect indices by setting the `NHoldAll` for `a`: `SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm not sure about `ListInterpolation`, but `Interpolation` does support interpolation of symbolic values. Thanks for referencing `NHoldAll`, that's a much cleaner way to work around this.

Comment: I would file this under "expected behavior" - it assumes that since the interpolating function takes real-valued input that it would give real-valued output.  You can replace `Array[a, 10]` by `Range[10]` in the post to make it more clear what is going on.

Comment: @JasonB I think, if I replace `Array[a, 10]` with `Range[10]`, this behavior becomes not only expected, but also desirable. Machine-precision computation is faster, and if the domain is to machine-precision, the interpolation ought to follow suit as well. I think, Alexey nailed the correct approach.

Comment: Note that the same thing happens with `Interpolation`: `Interpolation[Array[{N@#, a@#} &, 10]] // InputForm`. From this observation I suspect that it is a bug: the developer simply forgot to add a check for symbolic values of the function before applying `N` to them. Just a bit careless implementation, not the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`N` is indeed applied internally, when the interpolation is carried out to machine-precision, rather than arbitrary precision. This can be explicitly tested by the following:

```
Clear[a];
a /: N[a[x_Integer]] := (Print["N(a)"]; a[N@x])
ListInterpolation[Array[a, 10], {{1., 10.}}]
```

> N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>   N(a)
>
> ```
>  InterpolatingFunction[...]
> ```

This behavior has clear reasons. If the interpolation is done to machine-precision, rather than arbitrary precision, it makes no sense to leave the values at arbitrary precision. However, because `N` is rather aggressive in its listability, the correct approach is to protect the indices of the array by applying the attribute `NHoldAll` (rather than my workaround of `a[idx__Real] := a @@ (Floor /@ {idx});`).

```
SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll]
ListInterpolation[Array[a, 10], {{1., 10.}}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 10.}}, {5, 3, 0, {10},
> {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False},
> {{1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.}},
> {{a[1]}, {a[2]}, {a[3]}, {a[4]}, {a[5]}, {a[6]}, {a[7]}, {a[8]}, {a[9]}, {a[10]}},
> {Automatic}]
> ```